# NullPointerException raised eventhough it is not NULL

Tags: java, file-io, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

NullPointerException raise while trying update a excel cell using Apache POI. 
Particular cell that I want to update has some value but I can't update due to exception.

```
String excelFileName = "D:\\TempLocation\\Marks.xlsx";//name of excel file
String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName) ;
System.out.println(regNo+ " " + cellNo);
Cell cellToUpdate = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
cellToUpdate.setCellValue(mark);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
//write this workbook to an Outputstream.
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

this is my code. Exception raised at this line:

```
Cell cellToUpdate = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
```

Comment: They are 3 possible reasons. I recommend you to go step by step. First, `sheet` might be null, Secod, maybe sheet doesnt have row `0`, Third, maybe there is no cell `0`

Comment: Can you print `sheet.getRow(0)` and after that `sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0)` later?

Comment: `sheet` is `null` because you have not create one ! use `wb.createSheet()` before `wb.getSheet(sheetName)` or pass your file in constructor of `wb`

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what the values were?

Comment: @dams You are right. Sheet is null as I didn't pass any parameter to wb.getSheet(); Now it gets working after passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusion of this line

```
FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFileName));
```

And changes in this line

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Makes it to work.